# How to find certain 2 phrases or multiple phrases in a folder

Tags: powershell

This code executes and works when I look for "apple" in a file:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'S:\foler2\Private\Programs' -Recurse |
    Select-String -Pattern "apple"
```

but I want to look for "apple" and "orange" in a file.

What should I add to the code?

Comment: Are you looking for either one of the words or for both in the same document?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers  both in a file,please

Comment: Consider not trying to write this as one line, then optimize later if warranted.  Get files....search for first word...search those files for second word...and so on.  Depending on the number of files, their sizes, and the perf you desire, your solution can adapt accordingly.

Comment: If you're only looking for the files you could do something like this: `Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Select-String 'apple' | Get-Item | Select-String 'orange' | Select-Object -Expand Path`. Otherwise please explain in more detail what the desired result should be.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers if there are "apple" AND "Orange", if both exists in a file, I would like to see the file

Comment: The statement I outlined already gives you the path to those files. Append `| Invoke-Item` if you want to open the files instead of just seeing the path.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, I am sorry i am super new to powershell, how should I or where should I put | Invoke-Item?